# google-api-client to create short URL in java

Tags: java, google-api-client, short-url

I have a link that is way too long (got some URL-paramameters etc). I want to shorten this using the googpe API urlshortener. 
The API-key is created in google Developers Console. The key is an 'public API access' and a 'Key for server applications'.
Can anyone see why this code does not work? I have tried for way too long to make this happen.

```
 try {
        String g = "https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url";
        String url = g + "?key=secretKey"; 
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

        // add header
        //post.setHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

        //add the long url as a parameter
        List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longUrl", "www.google.com"));

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " 
         + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                       result.append(line);
        } } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Returns a responsecode of 400

Answer (score 1):

I guess there was just a problem with my HTTP-request. When I used the code used here: http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/216067/Call-Google-Shorten-URL-API it worked.

Posting this answer instead of just deleting the question, because the API is recently changed (I guess mid-2014), so there is not much updated examples of this.

Good luck to all of you trying to access this API :)